# Where Have I Gone Wrong? 2 Combinatorics Problems

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

Three physics books, five biology books, a dictionary  and two comic books are stored on a bookshelf.

(a) Determine the number of possible arrangements where the two comic books are not next to each other.

(b) If four books are selected randomly from the book shelf, what is the probability that exactly two physics books are selected?

I have an answer to both questions, but they are both wrong. I'm trying to figure out why but I can't.

For (a) I put $11!-10!$. Why is this wrong?

For (b) I put $3/11 \cdot 2/10 \cdot 8/9 \cdot 7/8$, but the answer is $1/110$. Why is that wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first, you need to figure out the number of possible arrangements. Your mistake is that you are overcounting. For example, if we place physics book first on the left, it does not matter which one of the three physics books is placed in that spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- (a): There are $10!\cdot \color{blue}{2!}$ arrangements with the comics beside each other. So, you need to subtract a bit more.
- (b): Since order does not matter, you get $\frac{\binom 3 2 \cdot \binom 8 2}{\binom{11}{4}}$. So, the given solution is wrong.

Comment: I get your answer to (a), but for (b), can you explain why your solution works?

Comment: @Ethan: will do. just give me a minute.

Comment: There are $11$ books. We choose randomly a set of $4$ books: This gives $\binom{11}{4}$ possible sets.
There are $\binom 3 2$ ways to choose a set of $2$ of the $3$ physics books.
There are $\binom 8 2$ ways to choose a set of $2$ of the $11-3 = 8$ other books.
Together, there are $\binom 3 2 \cdot  \binom 8 2$ ways to create a set of $4$ books that contains exactly 2 physics books.

Comment: Okay. Thank you!

Comment: @trancelocation: regading a): isn't the total number of possible arrangements $\frac{11!}{3!5!2!}$?

Comment: @Vasya: This would be correct if the books in each category (physics, comics, biology) were identical (a bit far from reality, I guess). As there is nothing said that they are identical, I assume them to be different.